# how to get path of application executer

Tags: windows, contextmenu

I am developing an application that can be accessed and executed from the right click context menu of windows explorer (much the same way as 7zip or winzip) and I would like to know how to get the path of the file that the application was executed from.

I know that I need to add registry in order to get the item to show up in the context menu, but i can't find any useful information on how to retrieve the path of the place from which the application was executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is a guide to writing .net Shell Extension Handlers which includes a sample. Hopefully your answer is in there. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/174369/How-to-Write-Windows-Shell-Extension-with-NET-Lang